# Swift: How to create stack of imageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Hey i want to create stack of imageview like the photo, how to do this

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? The image looks like three imageViews that overlap. Where have you run into problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add three imageviews with corner radius, border color, border width and bring the imageviews to from using [`bringSubviewToFront(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront) or [`insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622598-insertsubview)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        let imgView1 = createImageView()
        imgView1.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        view.addSubview(imgView1)

        let imgView2 = createImageView()
        imgView2.image = UIImage(named: "2")
        view.insertSubview(imgView2, belowSubview: imgView1)

        let imgView3 = createImageView()
        imgView3.image = UIImage(named: "3")
        view.insertSubview(imgView3, belowSubview: imgView2)

        imgView1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -75).isActive = true
        imgView1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView3.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 75).isActive = true
        imgView3.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    func createImageView() -> UIImageView {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 75
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        return imageView
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want infinite number of images I recommend to use collection view with custom layout. It's not the easiest way, but definitely the most extensible.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it?